# Dropdownlist boxes in gridview footer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a 2 DropDownList boxes in the footer of a Gridview and I am trying to update the value of another DropDownList box based on the selection made in the first box.

Basically, there are 2 DDLs. The user can pick from either one and the complimentary value of the value chosen is shown in the opposing box. (Yes, all complementary values exist on the opposing box's list.)

The boxes are populated as desired, but I can't seem to find the control even though I am in the SelectedIndexChanged Event.

Each DDL is in a unique column of the Gridview.

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim DDL1 As String = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
    Dim DDL2 As DropDownList = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2"), DropDownList)

    DDL2.SelectedValue = DDL1
End Sub
```

And the opposing box....

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim DDL1 As DropDownList = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)
    Dim DDL2 As String = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2"), DropDownList).SelectedValue


    DDL1.SelectedValue = DDL2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it bit differently. Here is the working version. The `sender` contains reference to the dropdownlist triggering the event. You can find the respective row and then the other dropdownlist in the row. Also you can not directly set `SelectedValue` for a dropdownlist like shown in your code, it has to be the way like shown below.

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
   Dim DDL1 As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
   Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DDL1.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
   Dim DDL2 As DropDownList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("DropDownList2"), DropDownList)

   Dim SelectedValue As String = DDL1.SelectedItem.Value
   DDL2.SelectedIndex = DDL2.Items.IndexOf(DDL2.Items.FindByValue(SelectedValue))
End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim DDL2 As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DDL2.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim DDL1 As DropDownList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("DropDownList1"), DropDownList)

    Dim SelectedValue As String = DDL2.SelectedItem.Value
    DDL1.SelectedIndex = DDL1.Items.IndexOf(DDL1.Items.FindByValue(SelectedValue))
End Sub
```

I used a tool to convert my C# code to VB.NET. The original C# code is below

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList DDL1 = (DropDownList)sender;
     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)DDL1.NamingContainer;
     DropDownList DDL2 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList2");

     string SelectedValue = DDL1.SelectedItem.Value;
     DDL2.SelectedIndex = DDL2.Items.IndexOf(DDL2.Items.FindByValue(SelectedValue));
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList DDL2 = (DropDownList)sender;
     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)DDL2.NamingContainer;
     DropDownList DDL1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

     string SelectedValue = DDL2.SelectedItem.Value;
     DDL1.SelectedIndex = DDL1.Items.IndexOf(DDL1.Items.FindByValue(SelectedValue));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. This looks great, let me plug it in and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, my SelectedIndex in both events is staying set to zero. Do I need to rebind?  This line is returning a -1  DDL2.Items.IndexOf(DDL2.Items.FindByValue(SelectedValue)). I know the value is in the list though. I can see it if I choose the opposing dropdown. Same for both events.

Comment: Okay, I converted to using the SelectedIndex and I got it working. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Here is the updated code for the first Event...  Dim SelectedValue As String = DDL1.SelectedItem.Value       DDL2.SelectedIndex = DDL2.Items.IndexOf(DDL2.Items.FindByText(SelectedValue))